# Shortcut toggle between debug configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code

has <s>anyout</s> anyone found a way (shortcut or navigation) without using the mouse to select different configurations before starting the debugger.

[image]

Is it also possible, when debugging multiple configurations, to select them without using the mouse.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64441752/can-i-select-per-language-debug-configurations-in-vs-code

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97921

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part (to start debug) is done with 1.10.1

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_debugging

> Ability to select and start a launch using keyboard The option to
>   launch debug configurations using just the keyboard (no mouse gesture
>   necessary) was added, as per this request. It works similarly to
>   running tasks, with an ability to launch a debugging session from the
>   Command Palette. The keyword 'debug ' or the command Debug: Select and
>   Start Debugging from the Command Palette is used to select and launch
>   a configuration from launch.json.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a custom keybinding for
command: `workbench.action.debug.selectandstart`
when: `!inDebugMode`