# Can I select per-language debug configurations in VS Code?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, launch

I have a multi-root workspace with code in R and Python. I have (mainly) two launch configurations: one for R code and one Python code. Each launch configuration comes with a `type` attribute, so VS Code knows exactly which one is suitable for which language.

I would like to use <kbd>F5</kbd> to start Debugging R code and Python code, but <kbd>F5</kbd> just starts the debug configuration currently selected in the "Run" panel, regardless of the language of the file currently open. As a consequence, many times have I started an R file in the Python interpreter, and vice versa.

How can I get this? Is there maybe an extension that selects the debug configuration based on the current editor? That would already solve my issue.

Comment: By the way, related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97921

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269815/shortcut-toggle-between-debug-configuration

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441851/how-to-call-other-extensions-in-a-extension-on-vscode

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109083